# Backbone collection filter

Tags: javascript, array, backbone.js

I've got this Collection in my Backbone application:

```
var AnswersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Answer,

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('Hello from new answers collection');
    },

    getCorrect: function() {
        return this.where({correct: true});
    },

    getWrong: function() {
        return this.where({correct: false});
    },

    randomSet: function(correct, wrong) {
        arr1 = _.sample(this.getCorrect(), correct);
        arr2 = _.sample(this.getWrong(), wrong);
        result = _.shuffle(arr1.concat(arr2));
        coll = new AnswersCollection(result)
        return coll;
    }

});
```

This works, and randomSet is called by a View when config have certain options or user click on 'rerender' button, but I'm wondering that maybe I can improve this code ?
The flow looks like this

1. Get randomly selected **X** correct answers
2. Get randomly selected **Y** wrong answers
3. Shuffle all answers
4. Create array of answers, that can be passed to new Collection

This code doesn't look to cool, maybe you will have some ideas how to make It cooler?:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reviewing code for *coolness* is a first ;)

Some observations:

- `initialize` : if really all you want to do there is *Hello World*, then you should take it out. `initialize` is meant for initializing your model with answers.
- `getCorrect` and `getWrong` are short one-liners that are called once, you should inline them
- `arr1`, `arr2`, `coll` and even `result` are pretty terrible names, how about `correctAnswers`, `wrongAnswers`, `answers` and not creating `coll` since you could return the results of new AnswersCollection immediately.
- The most serious problem though is that you are not declaring the prior mentioned variables with `var`, that is bad.

Also, from a *coolness* perspective, braces on their own line is where it's at.

I would counter-propose this:

```
var AnswersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend(
{
    model: Answer,

    randomSet: function(correct, wrong) 
    {
        var correctAnswers = _.sample(this.where({correct: true}), correct),
            wrongAnswers = _.sample(this.where({correct: false}), wrong),
            answers = _.shuffle(correctAnswers.concat(wrongAnswers));

        return new AnswersCollection( answers );
    }
});
```

Comment: braces on their own line is so PHP